# Regex to find first occurrence of a character unless it's in a certain set of characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a string like this:

```
key:value
```

But not match strings like these:

```
"has: stuff"
("or: that")
```

So far I've got a regex that looks like this:

```
^(.*?):
```

This is matching the all of these examples.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Clarify your question and post more good/bad examples. Your regex did NOT match other two examples, but that is what you wrote that you are looking for, to not match that, correct? So..? We need more information...

Comment: @Omega: The regex DOES match `"has: stuff"` (quotes are important)… I'm trying to match only like the first example which doesn't have quotes or parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your counterexamples, what are the factors that make them "invalid" for the purposes of this match?  Is it the punctuation at the start?  The space after the colon?

It sounds like you should just include what you want, rather than trying to exclude what you don't.  If your key/value pairs always consist of alphanumeric keys (i.e. no punctuation), then you can use a regex that simply looks for that.

```
/^([[:alnum:]]+):/
```

Comment: Yeah, this makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: The question is tagged python. If your example is supposed to include a capturing group with one or more alphanumeric characters, it would look like: `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+):` or `^(\w+):` which would include an underscore . The reviewers seemed to think I didn't understand what you were doing, so hopefully you can clarify this.

Comment: @HonestAbe - `\w` is supposed to be short-hand for `[:alnum:]` (per to [`grep(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep) which is an implementation of [`isalnum()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isalnum), which is combination of [`isalpha()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isalpha) and [`isdigit()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isdigit).  While in practice `\w` seems to match an underscore, that's not what's documented. I try not to use things whose behaviour is inconsistent with documentation, hence the character class instead of the shorthand.

Comment: I see; thanks for clearing that up. What I failed to mention was that `[:alnum:]` doesn't exist in the python regex dialect. [Reference](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: @HonestAbe - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex supports both POSIX character classes and unicode.

Comment: That's non-standard and was not specified in the question or tags.

Comment: Slashes are also not used in the python regex dialect.

Comment: Granted.  They are, however, often used to "quote" regexps, since they've been in use since BRE.  While I see your point, I do not believe including the slashes reduces the clarity of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To find a key you probably want to use regex `^\w+(?=:)` or `^(\w+):`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple regex pattern:

```
^(\w+)\:(\w+)$
```

`\w`: one character in the set [0-9a-zA-Z]

`\w+`: one or more \w characters

`^`: no other staff before the 1st (\w+)

`$`: no other staff after the 2nd (\w+)